# How to decode the google cloud storage md5 hash to a string produced by hash generators in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

Google cloud storage gives md5 hashes of [objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects) encoded in base64. An example would be `H0m5T/tigkNJLqL6+z9A7Q==`. I've tried to convert it using btoa(), but that results in `I9O{bCI."z{?@m` instead of the expected `b1f4f9a523e36fd969f4573e25af4540`.

I'm getting the string with `File.metadata.md5Hash` described [here](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/Google/Cloud/Storage/File.html)

Is there any way to convert this base64 -> `H0m5T/tigkNJLqL6+z9A7Q==` to this string -> `b1f4f9a523e36fd969f4573e25af4540` in node.js?

Code for reference:

```
async function getAllmd5()
{
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();
  var bucket = storage.bucket('example');

  var [files] = await bucket.getFiles();

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
  {
    console.log(Buffer.from(files[i].metadata.md5Hash, 'base64').toString("ascii"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show more details about the code you're writing that doesn't work the way you expect, especially how you get the hash from Cloud Storage.

Comment: I don't see that you've added any code.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm sorry. Do you see anyway to fix my problem? I can't decode the google cloud storage md5 hash to one typically generated.

Comment: The hash you are seeing is base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had the wrong thought process.

I was thinking: get data -> get hash -> encode to base64

The problem was that isn't how that works.
What you need to instead is to: get data -> get hash AS base64. Usually a program will output it as hex, which is fine for most cases, but in Google's it was a base64 md5, different from a hex one.

An example of how to get the md5 hash as base64:

```
//The modules we need:
const { md5 } = require('crypto-md5');
const { fs } = require('fs');

var filename "example.txt";

//Read the file content
var filecontent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, filename));

var hash = md5(filecontent, 'base64'); //Generate the md5 AS base64
```